# What blood type has been found on the relics of Jesus Christ here on earth?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, blood-of-christ

In contemporary times the best known, studied and discussed relic attributed to Jesus is the Shroud of Turin, currently kept in Turin and personal possession of the Pope. According to tradition, the Shroud is the sheet that had wrapped the body of Jesus in the tomb. The fabric is linen and measures 442x113 cm. It has the double image (front and back) of a man with a beard, mustache and long hair laying on the body the signs corresponding to the description of the passion: scourging, crowning with thorns, his hands and feet pierced by nails, spear wound in his side. The picture is not painted but comes from a gradual yellowing of textile fiber, as if it were a negative impression of a photographic film. In correspondence with the deepest wounds are traces of blood type AB.

The history of the Shroud is documented with certainty only from 1353, when the French Knight Geoffroy de Charny, who had fought in the Middle East, declared its possession. The Church has never officially ruled on the authenticity of the Shroud, but highly exalts the Shroud.

Are there other studies collaborating with the Shroud's results for Jesus' blood type? Are there any other similar scenarios that indicate what Jesus' blood type was?

Comment: How can we know, and why do you want to know?

Comment: If we assume Jesus had typical Jewish DNA then we could guess at his haplogroups, but there's no way we could know his ABO type.

Comment: Dna only lasts about 500 years. These tests weren't invented for 1800 years until after his death. Even if we could source a genuine artifact, time wouldn't preserve it.

Comment: I remember seeing someone assert that he was AB but thinking, and you know this why?

Comment: @AffableGeek Being AB- He would be the universal recipient - not rejecting any that would be grafted into him :)  Or perhaps He was O+ so that his blood can flow freely for the benefit of all? Either option seems spectacularly specious speculation.

Comment: cf. [blood type of the shroud of turin](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS569US569&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=blood%20type%20of%20the%20shroud%20of%20turin).

Comment: I would guess he would have been O Negative--the universal donor. : )

Comment: @Narnian - ah you're right - I should have had AB+ and O- as my alternatives

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too speculative

Answer (score 6):

We don't know. Medical science at the time he lived didn't trouble itself over details like blood type checks.

Nor will we ever know*. Jesus resurrection and ascension left no bodily remains to be posthumously examined for DNA clues. Even in the absurdly unlikely event that a physical relic such as piece of wood or cloth could be proved to have been in contact with him, there would still be no guarantee that blood traces or other organic matter was his and not from someone else.

Also, as far as Christianity is concerned, it doesn't matter anyway.

<sub>* At least not in this world. I suppose if you still think it's relevant you could ask him in the next, but I have an idea all priorities will be re-ordered and if he tells you it will be for a purpose—something there isn't  currently.</sub>

Comment: `Nor will we ever know` -- we might upon the second coming... if he submits to blood tests at that time :)

Comment: @Flimzy Ah but is blood group conserved post-resurrection? ;)

Comment: "Also, as far as Christianity is concerned, it doesn't matter anyway." Talk about it enough and it will start to matter to someone. It might already.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Ah but "flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God" 1 Corinthians 15:50. I would be entirely surprised if blood groups are still relevant to our spiritual bodies (1 Cor 15:44). Plus doubt there is need for an immune system to fight off blood with A B markers :)

Answer (score 0):

Christ's relics on earth be them fake or real is up for a big debate however most of the relics are blood group AB even the statues that cry blood have come back testing as blood group ab. Cnn's special on finding Jesus surprinsingly left this out however it did reference at the very end that the sodarium and the shroud tested blood came back both the same blood type. There is a ton of misinformation going around the internet about this and the best websites quote from the scientific data from the original study of the shroud which by the way even the scientist now agree that all evidence besides the carbon dating test point this out to being real. Anyway in the study they were able to test for blood type and get the result of blood type ab. It also states that the blood was to degraded to test for other markers such as being negative or positive. It is also worth noting that when you google this you get many crazy claims like all old blood turns to ab or another one is that blood group ab never even existed until 1000 years ago. Blood group ab is the rarest of the four blood groups and is found today in 3% to 7% of the now population.(in north america)

Shroud- scroll down to pg.11 of report   http://www.shroud.com/pdfs/kearse.pdf

Sudarium of Oviedo        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarium_of_Oviedo

Miracle of Lanciano       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_Lanciano

Host in Buenos Aires      http://thedivinemercy.org/shrine/story.php?NID=5114

The Holy eucharist in Naju    http://www.marys-touch.com/truth/descents.htm

Weeping Madonna of Syracuse  http://www.jnsr.be/uk_lacrymations.htm

about blood and types http://www.redcrossblood.org/learn-about-blood/blood-types

Comment: I'm assuming it was you who submitted that edit? If so, logging in would allow you to submit that edit without requiring it to be approved by the community.